# Adding a namespace to just one element

Tags: xslt

How do I only add a namespace to the root element?

My XML:

```
<Envelope>
    <from>
        <contents />
    </from>
</Envelope>
```

My desired output:

```
<Envelope xmlns:tns="Foo">
    <from>
        <contents />
    </from>
</Envelope>
```

I can only get "xmlns='Foo'" using this, not "xmlns:tns=..":

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="Foo" >
        <xsl:copy-of select="attribute::*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: Buffalo: I had initially misunderstood the question -- and was alerted by SeanB.Durkin. Since then I have corrected the answer -- please, use the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:tns="Foo">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
       <xsl:copy-of select=
        "document('')/*/namespace::*[name()='tns']"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Envelope>
    <from>
        <contents />
    </from>
</Envelope>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Envelope xmlns:tns="Foo">
   <from>
      <contents/>
   </from>
</tns:Envelope>
```

Comment: My reading of the question was that the Envelope element was not to be part of the Foo namespace. Something seems amiss here. Compare Buffalo's "My desired output" fragment with your "the wanted, correct result is produced" fragment.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: Now that I look at it -- you are right! I will correct the answer shortly.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin and to whomever downvoted: I had initially misunderstood the question, but the answer is now correct, after I was alerted by SeanBDurkin. Please, revert the downvote.

Comment: I didn't down-vote and wouldn't for something that is potentially just just a different interpretation of a question. Sometimes SO seems like a game where each player tries to guess the true meaning of an ambiguous question with missing information, and the winner is the one who guesses right,